# How to resolve a namespace as root in C# [CS0234]

Tags: c#, namespaces, cs0246

Specifics:
When specifying a BindingSource in WinForms the toolchain sets the DataSource to the type you're associating using absolute namespaces (to avoid any `using` statements). I'm using a data type `Project.Namespace1.MyType`, but the compiler is saying that the type `LibraryX.Subdomain.Namespace1.MyType` doesn't exist.

Additional details:
When editing the auto-generated code to specify `using Project.Namespace1;` and removing `Project.Namespace1` from the latter call, the issue is resolved.

Thus the question: How does namespace resolution explain this?